# Playwright testing. Can I use a variable in ':has-text()'

Tags: typescript, playwright

Using Playwright, I'd like to find an element using the value of a variable

For example:

```js
let name = 'Sully'
await page.click(`li:has-text(${sully})`)
```

but I get the following error:

`page.click: Error: "has-text" engine expects a single string`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have to add single or double quotes to the `has-text` function and use the `name` variable instead of `sully` or declare it.

Hence, it should be like this:

```js
let name = 'Sully';

//                            ↓       ↓ - missed quotes       
await page.click(`li:has-text('${name}')`)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### **Don't use css based selectors directly or even Page.click()**

[These are not recommended by playwright docs anymore](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#locate-by-css-or-xpath).

> **"XPath and CSS selectors can be tied to the DOM structure or
> implementation. These selectors can break when the DOM structure
> changes. Long CSS or XPath chains can lead to unstable tests."**

`Page.click` is also [discouraged](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-click).

#### Use [Locators](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator) with [filters](https://playwright.dev/docs/locators#filtering-locators) instead:

In comparison, locators are dynamic and don't depend on page structure.

```
 let name = 'Sully'
 await page
    .getByRole('listitem')
    .filter({ hasText: name})
    .click();
```