# Playwright & Javascript - Variable inside of has-text locator not functioning

Tags: javascript, css, playwright

I am attempting to use a variable inside of a has-text locator to click the selected Country from a dropdown webpage button element.

My code is:

```
  const dropdown = page.locator(".ta-results");
  let country = "India";
  console.log(country);
  await dropdown.waitFor();
  await page.locator(".ta-results:has-text('${country}')").click();
```

The dropdown is a country selector that autofills based on what you type, so typing "ind" pulls up Indonesia, India, etc. and I am trying to get it to click on "India". By using `".ta-results:has-text('India')").click();` it works fine.

For the course I'm taking the 2nd option works just fine but I would like to find out how to get it to accept a variable for future use.

Based on this [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70684813/playwright-testing-can-i-use-a-variable-in-has-text) it should work. Here is the failure:

```
=========================== logs ===========================
waiting for locator('.ta-results:has-text(\'${country}\')')
============================================================

  92 |   console.log(country);
  93 |   await dropdown.waitFor();
> 94 |   await page.locator(".ta-results:has-text('${country}')").click();
     |                                                            ^
  95 |   await page.pause();
  96 | });
  97 |
```

Comment: `".ta-results:has-text('${country}')"` should use the backtick template literal syntax instead of double quotes `"`. You can  tell from the autoformatter that it's putting `${country}` in literally rather than injecting a variable.

Answer (score 1):

Note that in the question you linked, they were using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals), a string surrounded by backticks (`` ` ``) which in JavaScript allows interpolation, or inserting things like variables or other expressions, unlike some other languages where double quotes allows this. So you just need to switch the quote type on your string like so:

```js
`.ta-results:has-text('${country}')`
```

You could also use one of the filter option approaches provided by Playwright:

1. Using [the `hasText` option specific to the `locator` method](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-locator-option-has):

   ```js
   await page.locator(".ta-results”, { hasText: country }).click();
   ```
2. Using [the `hasText` option within the `filter` method](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-filter-option-has-text):

   ```js
   await page.locator(".ta-results”).filter({ hasText: country }).click();
   ```

Comment: The rich text quotes here break the syntax.